# What could be the possible reasons why robot framework can't detect elements even if they are existing?

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

What could be the possible reasons why robot framework can't detect elements even if they are existing? Please check below codes and reference to attached image.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=nav_registration1    150s
Click Element    id=nav_registration1
sleep    10s    Wait for the page to load

Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=edit-span-company_tin    10s
sleep    2s    Wait for the page to load
Click Element    id=edit-span-company_tin
sleep    10s    Wait for the page to load
Wait Until Element Is Visible    id=companyTin    10s
sleep    1s    Wait for the page to load
Input Text    id=companyTin    001-748-412
Capture Page Screenshot
```

[image: robotframework]

Comment: Does the screenshot in the log show that it is visible?

Answer (score 1):

- Shadow DOM
- element is inside iframe - and you didn't `Select Window`.
- Incorrect selector

Comment: Thank you @rasjani, this solved some of my issues but not all..